# Displaying tabular data on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, listfield

I basically want to replicate this on the blackberry - http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/4628/tempi.jpg

Is there a simple way of doing it instead of messing around with the graphics object of ListView?

Thanks, 
Teja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the "[Displaying a List of Complex Records](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/List%20Of%20Complex%20Records.zip)" (zip file) sample from the [Blackberry Development Labs](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/developer_labs.jsp#tab_tab_jde) page.

It teaches you how to implement a class called TableListField, and includes a completed source file that you can use. The TableListField basically lets you place multiple items in a row of a ListField and select the whole row.

Comment: Wow, you and Marc are awesome. Not sure where I'd be stuck without you! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to implement your own `ListFieldCallback` implementation the only other "pre-built" implementation is the `ObjectListField` class - but you'd be limited to a list of strings and it looks like you want a lot more control over the UI including fixed-width columns with multiple pieces of data, image, etc.

So basically - the only way to render a custom UI such as the one you want is by implementing your own `ListFieldCallback` including the `drawListRow()` method.